# passing the entire email body as a string and rendering email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm working on a project which is in rails 5.2. I'm using the rails action mailer to send the email.

I have to send the entire email template as an input to an action mailer.

so far I have overridden the mail method of the action mailer.

```
class UAMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def mail(headers = {}, &block)
    super(headers.merge(template_path: template_path), &block)
  end
end
```

I'm calling this from one method called say send_email.

```
def send_email(user, subject)
  mail(to: user.email, subject: subject)
end
```

then I have a normal **send_email.html.erb** a template where the actual mailer body is written.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
 </head>
<body>
  <p>Dear <%= @user.username %>,</p>
  <p>Testing</p>
</body>
```

I want to pass this entire body as an input to the mail method defined earlier. entire HTML body tag I need to pass to the overridden mail method.

```
def send_email(user, subject, body)
  mail(to: user.email, subject: subject, body: body)
end
```

Comment: If you will put value in any instance variable you can directly access that value in your email template. Like: `@body = body` and in the template you can call `<%= @body.html_safe %>`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra thanks. if u add this as an answer I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any instance variable added under email action is directly accessible in its corresponding email template.

For. Eg.

```
@body = body
```

and in the template, you can call

```
<%= @body.html_safe %>
```

For HTML safe content `html_safe`